FastDDS ShapesDemo Application Can not Communicate with Simulink DDS Blockset ShapesDemo EXE
I followed the MATLAB/Simulink tutorial Creat DDS Applications in Simulink and have build the shapesdemo.exe successfully. I have also installed eProsima FastDDS ShapesDemo Application. In ShapesDemo Application, the Square was setted as Publisher and Circle was setted as Subscriber, which is consistent with shapesdemo Simulink model.
However, after I start the ShapesDemo Application and run the ! shapesdemo.exe command in MATLAB Command Window, there is no response in ShapesDemo Application as illustrated in the following image:
ShapesDemo App Image
